# Is the “T-Coding Method” a reliable method to learn vocabulary?

Tags: learning-methods, vocabulary, mnemonics

In Iran someone named "Mr Taraghghi" has imported a method for learning English vocabulary called "Vocabulary Coding" for Persian native speakers that works like this example:

**Consider the word "deliberate". In Persian, "deli" means something depends on the heart and the human's will, and "berate" means "for you". With both parts combined, "deliberate" is like saying: "I have done this work for you with my heart (not casual)", which is similar to the concept of the word "deliberate".**

Does anyone have any idea about this method? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't find any sources for this method, could you share a link?

Comment: @FrancescoDondi I just could find [this link On Iran Daily](http://www.iran-daily.com/News/125250.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this method is better known as the "keyword method" or the "keyword mnemonic". The technique was introduced by Richard C. Atkinson's 1975 article [Mnemotechnics in Second Language Learning](http://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ123584). There has been research on this method and it appears to be quite effective.

According to [Fiona McPherson](http://www.mempowered.com/strategies/keyword-method) it works best when:

- you come up with your own connections to the keyword,
- you combine the method with [retrieval practice](http://www.mempowered.com/strategies/retrieval-practice-keyword-mnemonic) (or [spaced repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition)).

For research, see for example:

- Hauptmann, Joern: [The Effect of the Integrated Keyword Method on Vocabulary Retention and Motivation](http://www.keyword-method.de/own_docs/pdf/thesis.pdf). Thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Education at the University of Leicester, January 2004.
- Khalafi, Zeynab; Oroji, Mohammad Reza: [The Impact of Using Keyword Method on Vocabulary Learning and Retention: A Case of Iranian Intermediate EFL Learners](http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/html/10.11648.j.ijll.20160401.12.htm). *International Journal of Language and Linguistics*, Volume 4, Issue 1 , January 2016, Pages:9-13.
- Taheri, Ali Akbar; Davoudi, Mohammad: [The Effect of the Keyword Method on Vocabulary Learning and Long-Term Retention](http://ijllnet.com/journals/Vol_3_No_1_March_2016/10.pdf), International Journal of Language and Linguistics, Volume 3, No. 1; March 2016.
- Since some people on Language Learning SE are interested in Japanese: Kobayashi, Rika: [The Effectiveness of the Keyword Method in Kanji Acquisition for Second Language Learners](https://web.duke.edu/APSI/events/Conferencedocuments/SEATJ2010/ProceedingsPapers/Kobayashi.pdf), Proceedings of SEATJ (Southeastern Association of Teachers of Japanese) 2010. (Kobayashi finds that the technique works best when learners come up with their own assocations; however, the study was limited in that it involved learning only 10 kanji and it tested retention only up to 1 week.)

Based on this keyword mnemonic, **Mohsen Taraghi Gashti** came up with his **T-coding system**, which he claims is much better than the original keyword technique (see the [article in the Iran Daily](http://www.iran-daily.com/News/125250.html) and the [abstract from the Jil Jadid conference](http://www.jil-jadid.org/abstracts/mohsen-taraghi-gashti/)). He has presented his method at a few conferences, but I have not been able to find any full papers by him. One cannot judge a method's effectiveness based on a single newspaper article and an abstract.

Comment: Apparently, however, here you don't 'come up with your own connections to the keyword'. Rather, you buy a book which claims to have the 'best' connections, handpicked once for all. Of which he gives an example with *deliberate*. I think the question is asking if *this* is more effective than coming up with your own.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi Mohsen Taraghi Gashti has presented his T-coding system at a few conferences, but I have not been able to find any papers by him. One cannot judge the method's effective based on a single newspaper article.

Comment: that's what the question is asking though.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi That was not clear from the initial description, since it did not say "T-coding".

Answer (score 1):

My name is Mohse Taraghi Gashti (TEFL PhD Candidate at Tehran University). If there are any questions, I would be glad to answer accordingly. Here is my e-mail: m.taraghi@yahoo.com. 
The following is the link to my presentation at the Universitat Autònoma de Barcelona:https://ijas2016barcelona.sched.org/mobile/#session:192ae33ebcf46ffa84618e08fbe4b35a.
The next link guides you to the conference at Texas University:
http://www.jil-jadid.org/abstracts/mohsen-taraghi-gashti/
Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning!

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers are prone to linkrot and are usually discouraged on StackExchange.